# three.js r88 meshdepthmaterial there is no effect

Tags: three.js

I'm a new three.js men, and below is my code snippet...
In three.js docs said that the MeshDepthMaterial is drawing geometry by depth. Depth is based off of the camera near and far plane. White is nearest, black is farthest. But in my case, there is no effect for three.js r88, but three.js r 67. Can anybody please tell me why? Thanks very much...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>示例 04.02 - MeshDepthMaterial</title>
 <script src="../build/three.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js"></script>
 <script src="../build/js/renderers/Projector.js"></script>
 <script src="../jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            /* 设置 margin 为 0，并且 overflow 为 hidden，来完成页面样式 */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
  /* 统计对象的样式 */
  #Stats-output {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- 用于 WebGL 输出的 Div -->
<div id="webgl-output"></div>
<!-- 用于统计 FPS 输出的 Div -->
<div id="stats-output"></div>

<!-- 运行 Three.js 示例的 Javascript 代码 -->
<script type="text/javascript">

 var scene;
 var camera;
 var render;
 var webglRender;
 var canvasRender;
 var controls;
 var stats;
 var guiParams;
 
 var ground;
 var cube;
 var plane;
 var sphere;
 
 var meshMaterial;
 
 var ambientLight;
 var spotLight;

    $(function() {
  stats = initStats();
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.overrideMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial({
   morphTargets: true
  });
  
  webglRender = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true, alpha: true, logarithmicDepthBuffer: true} ); // antialias 抗锯齿
  webglRender.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  webglRender.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
  webglRender.shadowMap.enabled = true; // 允许阴影投射
  render = webglRender;
  
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000); // 2147483647
  camera.position.set(-50, 40, 50);
  
  var target = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0 , 0);
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, render.domElement);
  controls.target = target;
  camera.lookAt(target);
  
  $('#webgl-output')[0].appendChild(render.domElement);
  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
  
  ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x000000);
  scene.add(ambientLight);
  
  /** 用来保存那些需要修改的变量 */
  guiParams = new function() {
   this.rotationSpeed = 0.02;
   this.near = 2;
   this.far = 50;
   
   this.addCube = function() {
    for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
     // 定义 cube 几何
     var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5);
     // 定义网格材质
     meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: Math.random() * 0xffffff});
     // 定义 cube 网格
     cube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, meshMaterial);
     cube.castShadow = true;
     cube.position.x = -60 + Math.round((Math.random() * 100));
     cube.position.y = Math.round((Math.random() * 10));
     cube.position.z = -100 + Math.round((Math.random() * 150));
     // 默认加入 cube
     scene.add(cube);
    }
   };
  }
  /** 定义 dat.GUI 对象，并绑定 guiParams 的几个属性 */
  var gui = new dat.GUI();
  gui.add(guiParams, 'addCube');
  gui.add(guiParams, 'near', 0, 50).onChange(function(e) {
   camera.near = e;
  });
  gui.add(guiParams, 'far', 5, 200).onChange(function(e) {
   camera.far = e;
  });
  
  guiParams.addCube();
  
  renderScene();
    });
 
 /** 渲染场景 */
 function renderScene() {
  stats.update();
  rotateMesh(); // 旋转物体
  
  requestAnimationFrame(renderScene);
  render.render(scene, camera);
 }
 
 /** 初始化 stats 统计对象 */
 function initStats() {
  stats = new Stats();
  stats.setMode(0); // 0 为监测 FPS；1 为监测渲染时间
  $('#stats-output').append(stats.domElement);
  return stats;
 }
 
 /** 当浏览器窗口大小变化时触发 */
 function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  render.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
 }
 
 /** 旋转物体 */
 function rotateMesh() {
  scene.traverse(function(mesh) {
   if (mesh instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
    mesh.rotation.x += guiParams.rotationSpeed;
    mesh.rotation.y += guiParams.rotationSpeed;
    mesh.rotation.z += guiParams.rotationSpeed;
   }
  });
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change `camera.near` or `camera.far` you need to call:

```
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
```

three.js r.88

Comment: Thanks WestLangley. But now there is a new question, that is in my case, the white is fartest, and the black is nearest, why?

Comment: Because that is how it was coded. See [fragment shader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/depth_frag.glsl).

Comment: Because near < far. If you map near and far to 0-1, near will be 0, far will be 1.